# How to add correctly use Meteor package in a angular2-meteor project?

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I am writing an angular2-meteor program.

When I am using [urigo:angular2-meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/urigo/angular2-meteor) package, I add reference path like this:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />
```

The question is: can I use other normal meteor packages in a angular2-meteor project? Or I can only use some packages written for angular2-meteor specifically.

For example, if I want to use [yuukan:streamy](https://atmospherejs.com/yuukan/streamy), how can I use it correctly? Right now, I have one line code

```
Streamy.broadcast('hello', {data: 'world!'});
```

When I compile it, it shows: `Cannot find name 'Streamy'.`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use all the libraries from meteor.

you will have 2 choices.

1. find the streamy definition file (streamy.d.ts) if it exists. This will give you autocompletion and compile errors if you misuse streamy functions.
2. If you dont find a definition file than just add `declare var Streamy` at the top of the file you want to use it. The library is already there if you add it via `atmosphere`. But typescript does not know about it. By declaring the variable you tell typescript that this exists and it wont complain when compiling.

Comment: Thanks, @litttleStudent! The second way will take me some time to test it. I will let you know the result!

Comment: I try to use `Streamy.broadcast('hello', {data: 'world!'});` Now, my WebStorm does not show any error. But Chrome console shows: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Streamy is not defined; ReferenceError: Streamy is not defined`. And the codes after `Streamy.broadcast('hello', {data: 'world!'});` didn't run.

Comment: The following steps worked for me:

1. meteor add yuukan:streamy

2. (on the client) add `declare var Streamy:any`
3. (on the client) add `Streamy.on('hello', function(d, s) {...}`
4. (on the client) add `Streamy.broadcast('hello', {data: 'world!'});` below

Comment: Sorry to reply late. I just got time to test. Thank you so much! it is working!